# Formula help with this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I don't know what the answer to this formula is, can someone please help me.

I've tried lots of things but getting no where.

If $x=\dfrac56+\dfrac{15}{18}-\dfrac{10}{12}$, then $(x-1)3=$ ?

Comment: OP *may* have meant $(x - 1)^3$. Writing $(x - 1)3$ instead of $3(x - 1)$ is at least not  used widely.

Comment: @ParthKohli - If the OP did mean $(x-1)^3$, the simplifications for $x$ provided in the answers so far will still be useful. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Yes, that is correct!  Still, might be useful to point out.

Comment: @ParthKohli - Thanks, I've incorporated your suggestion in an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $x=5/6+15/18-10/12$ may be simplified considerably:

\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{5}{6}+\frac{15}{18}-\frac{10}{12}\\
&= \frac{5}{6}+\left(\frac{30}{36}-\frac{30}{36}\right)\\
&= \frac{5}{6}.
\end{align*}

Thus, $x-1=-\frac{1}{6}$ and $3(x-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

As @ParthKohli has pointed out in a comment, you may actually be interested in the expression $(x-1)^3$, rather than in $(x-1)3$. If that's the case, you can still use the simplification for $x$ provided above to obtain
$$(x-1)^3=-\frac{1^3}{6^3}=-\frac{1}{216}.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x&=5/6+15/18-10/12\\
x-1&=5/6+15/18-10/12- 3/3\\
(x-1)3&=(5/6+15/18-10/12- 3/3)3\\
(x-1)3&=3*5/6+3*15/18-3*10/12- 3*3/3\\
(x-1)3&=5/2+15/6-10/4- 3\\
(x-1)3&=5/2+5/2-5/2- 3\\
(x-1)3&=5/2- 3\\
(x-1)3&=5/2- 6/2\\
(x-1)3&=-1/2
\end{align}

Comment: Should that be `-3*1` instead of `-3*3` at the end of the fourth line?

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!